# How to run task after clean in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm Android Developer.

How to run a task(like methodA) after clean the project?

In other words,I want to execute a method after clean my Android project

Thanks!

Comment: You cant execute a method after cleaning a project.

Comment: How can I execute the method after cleaning my project?@Enzokie

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle:

```
def methodA() {
    print "Method A"
}

tasks['clean'] << {
    methodA()
}
```

The `<<` operator is a shorthand to add a "do last" closure to a task. Alternatively:

```
tasks['clean'].doLast({
    methodA()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
task removeSomeStuff(type: Delete) {
    //some stuff after  clean
    delete file('projectFilesBackup')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
    finalizedBy removeSomeStuff
}
```